# VHDL process if-then-else-if statement

Tags: debugging, if-statement, process, vhdl, modelsim

I Edited this thread to update my whole new project and make it more readable:

```
--Propagate & generate team--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
ENTITY PG_team_1bit IS
    PORT(a, b:IN STD_LOGIC;
         p: OUT STD_LOGIC;
         g: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END PG_team_1bit;
ARCHITECTURE PG_team_1bit_arch OF PG_team_1bit IS
BEGIN
    p <= a XOR b;
    g <= a AND b;      
END PG_team_1bit_arch;       


--Grey Box--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
ENTITY Grey_box IS
    PORT(P, G, Gminus:IN STD_LOGIC;
         NewG: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END Grey_box;
ARCHITECTURE Grey_box_arch OF Grey_box IS
    SIGNAL temp: STD_LOGIC;
BEGIN
   temp <= P AND Gminus;
   NewG <= G OR temp;      
END Grey_box_arch;       


--Black Box--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
ENTITY Black_box IS
    PORT(P, G, Pminus, Gminus:IN STD_LOGIC;
         NewP, NewG: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END Black_box;
ARCHITECTURE Black_box_arch OF Black_box IS
    SIGNAL temp: STD_LOGIC;
BEGIN
   NewP <= P AND Pminus;
   temp <= P AND Gminus;  
   NewG <= G or temp;    
END Black_box_arch;   


--Full adder--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
ENTITY Full_Adder IS
    PORT(A, B, Cin:IN STD_LOGIC;
         S, Cout: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END Full_Adder;
ARCHITECTURE Full_Adder_arch OF Full_Adder IS
    SIGNAL p: STD_LOGIC;
BEGIN
   p <= A XOR B;
   S <= p XOR Cin;  
   Cout <= (A AND B) OR (A AND Cin) OR (B AND Cin);    
END Full_Adder_arch;  



--SKLANSKY SPARSE TREE ADDER 32 bit--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
ENTITY SSTA32 IS
    PORT(A, B:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
         S: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(32 downto 0));
END SSTA32;
ARCHITECTURE SSTA32_arch of SSTA32 IS 
    SIGNAL con: STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL p: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    SIGNAL g: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    SIGNAL NewGG: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);
    SIGNAL NewP: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);
    SIGNAL NewBG: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);
    variable j : integer := 0;
    variable k : integer := 0;
    variable l : integer := 0;
    variable m : integer := 0;
    variable d : integer := 0;
    variable e : integer := 0;
COMPONENT PG_team_1bit
    PORT(a, b:IN STD_LOGIC;
         p: OUT STD_LOGIC;
         g: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT; 
COMPONENT Grey_box IS
    PORT(P, G, Gminus:IN STD_LOGIC;
         NewG: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;
COMPONENT Black_box IS
    PORT(P, G, Pminus, Gminus:IN STD_LOGIC;
         NewP, NewG: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;
COMPONENT Full_Adder IS
    PORT(A, B, Cin:IN STD_LOGIC;
         S, Cout: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;
BEGIN 
   con <= '1';
   GENERATE_LABEL_1:
   FOR i IN 0 TO 31 GENERATE
      PG_team_1bit_i: PG_team_1bit PORT MAP(a(i), b(i), p(i), g(i));
   END GENERATE GENERATE_LABEL_1;   
   GENERATE_LABEL_2: 
   FOR i IN 0 TO 31 GENERATE
       BEGIN
          F0 : IF ((i=1) OR (i=5) OR (i=9) OR (i=13) OR (i=17) OR (i=21) OR (i=25) OR (i=29)) GENERATE
             BEGIN Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(p(i), g(i), g(i-1), NewGG(j));--
             j := j+1;
             END GENERATE F0;
          F1 : IF ((i/=1) AND (i/=5) AND (i/=9) AND (i/=13) AND (i/=17) AND (i/=21) AND (i/=25) AND (i/=29)) GENERATE
             BEGIN Black_box_i: Black_box PORT MAP(p(i), g(i), p(i-1), g(i-1), NewP(k), NewBG(k));
             k := k+1;
             END GENERATE F1; 
       END GENERATE GENERATE_LABEL_2;
   GENERATE_LABEL_3:
   FOR i IN 0 TO 31 GENERATE
      BEGIN
         F2 : IF (i=3) GENERATE
            BEGIN Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(NewP(m), NewBG(m), NewGG(m), DNewG);
            m := m+1;
            END GENERATE F2;
         F3 : IF ((i=7) OR (i=11) OR (i=15) OR (i=19) OR (i=23) OR (i=27) OR (i=31)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Black_box_i: Black_box PORT MAP(NewP(m), NewBG(m), con, NewBG(m), TNewP(l), TNewBG(l));
            l := l+1; 
            END GENERATE F3;
      END GENERATE GENERATE_LABEL_3;
   GENERATE_LABEL_4:
   FOR i IN 0 TO 31 GENERATE 
      BEGIN
         F4 : IF (i=3) GENERATE
            BEGIN C(d) <= '0';
            d := d+1;
            C(d) <= NOT DNewG;
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F4;
         F5 : IF (i=7) GENERATE
            BEGIN Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(TNewP(e), TNewBG(e), DNewG, DNewG2);
            C(d) <= NOT DNewG2;
            d := d+1;
            e := e+1;
            END GENERATE F5;
         F6 : IF (i=11) GENERATE
            BEGIN Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(NOT TNewP(e), NOT TNewBG(e), DNewG2, C(d));
            d := d+1;
            e := e+1;
            END GENERATE F6;
         F7 : IF (i=15) GENERATE
            BEGIN Black_box_i: Black_box PORT MAP(TNewP(e), TNewBG(e), TNewP(e-1), TNewBG(e-1), QNewP, QNewBG);
            Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(QNewP, QNewBG, DNewG2, DNewG3);
            C(d) <= DNewG3;
            d := d+1;
            e := e+1;
            END GENERATE F7;
         F8 : IF (i=19) GENERATE
            BEGIN Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(NOT TNewP(e), NOT TNewBG(e), DNewG3, C(d));
            d := d+1;
            e := e+1;
            END GENERATE F8;
         F9 : IF (i=23) GENERATE
            BEGIN Black_box_i: Black_box PORT MAP(TNewP(e), TNewBG(e), TNewP(e-1), TNewBG(e-1), PNewP, PNewBG);
            Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(PNewP, PNewBG, DNewG3, C(d));
            d <= d+1;
            e <= e+1;
            END GENERATE F9;
         F10 : IF (i=27) GENERATE
            BEGIN Black_box_i: Black_box PORT MAP(NOT TNewP(e), NOT TNewBG(e), PNewP, PNewBG, HNewP, HNewBG);
            Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(HNewP, HNewBG, DNewG3, C(d));
            END GENERATE F10;
      END GENERATE GENERATE_LABEL_4;
   d := 0;
   GENERATE_LABEL_5:
   FOR i IN 0 TO 31 GENERATE
      BEGIN
         F11 : IF ((i=0) AND (d=0)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d);
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F11;
         F12 : IF ((i=4) AND (d=1)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d);
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F12;
         F13 : IF ((i=8) AND (d=2)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d);
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F13;
         F14 : IF ((i=12) AND (d=3)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d);
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F14;
         F15 : IF ((i=16) AND (d=4)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d); 
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F15;
         F16 : IF ((i=20) AND (d=5)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d);
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F16;
         F17 : IF ((i=24) AND (d=6)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d);
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F17;
         F18 : IF ((i=28) AND (d=7)) GENERATE
            BEGIN Cin <= C(d);
            d := d+1;
            END GENERATE F18; 
         Full_Adder_i: Full_Adder PORT MAP(a(i), b(i), Cin, S(i), Cout);
         Cin <= Cout;
         F19 : IF (i=31) GENERATE
            BEGIN S(32) <= Cout;
            END GENERATE F19;
      END GENERATE GENERATE_LABEL_5;
END SSTA32_arch;
```

The errors that I get are the following :
-Not static signal names for almost all the signals I use.
-Variable Declaration not allowed where I did it.
-Unknown Identifiers.
-Illegal target for signal assignment and
-Illegal concurent statement.

Any tips to fix them? 
Also is my generate if now correct?I changed that to avoid processes.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Step back a bit; it is clear that you aren't used to VHDL yet; it is a bit different from other languages and the differences are frankly (IMO) not very well taught in many (most?) books.

Fixing syntax errors won't get you through this; learn to see the conceptual errors behind them.

Some texts stress that VHDL is a Hardware Description Language not a programming language : while true, this isn't particularly helpful and can lead you into poor low-level design practices. Here's a different view...

VHDL is virtually two different languages in one : a sequential language like Pascal or C, and a parallel processing language like ... I can't think of a good example, but perhaps a functional programming language like ML or Haskell (bear with me on this bit...) where things happen in parallel and not in any specific order : the real strength of VHDL is that it does so [safely!](http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel)

Within a process, you can treat it like a sequential language, with functions, procedures (void functions to C programmers!), variables, loops, if/then/else, and familiar sequential semantics - with ONE exception : [Signals have different semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532) because they are the means of communicating between (usually different) processes. (A typical C program is a single process : if you write multi-threaded C programs you will know you need a very different discipline for them and extra support like a threads library).

The other aspect of VHDL is the parallel aspect, where you create multiple units - essentially all processes operating independently of each other, communicating via signals. Outside a process, you have a different set of programming tools:

- Entities/architectures are wrappers around a group of processes.
- Components are the same, because they simply map to entities (via
  configurations, to allow you to select different entities or
  architectures). If you don't need to remap them, you can eliminate
  components and directly instantiate entities in a design.
- Simple signal assignments like 
     `p <= A XOR B`; outside of a process are shorthand for a complete process wrapping up that single assignment.
- There are also conditional signal assignments and selected signal assignments, e.g.

  `p <= A when B = '1' else C;` These are again shorthand for processes.
- Wiring up multiple parallel processes gets tedious : the `Generate` statements are tools to automate that job.

It is a mistake to mix the two domains : such as using if/then/else or variable assignment `a := b;` outside a process, or to instantiate a component or use `Generate` inside one. Now, inside `ARCHITECTURE SSTA32_arch of SSTA32` you can see such mistakes...

I'm not going to fix your project and I don't think you want me to; but here are a couple of pointers:

- While you *can* use variables and variable assignment outside a process, it is **usually a mistake** : these are known as "shared variables" and (in C programmer terms) **not thread-safe** and won't usually do what you expect. Using signals (and learning their semantics) is the way to go here.
- While you can't use `if a then b else c;` outside a process, you CAN use `if a generate b; end generate; if not a generate c; end generate;` and you can nest generate statements.
- better formatting will make it easier to read and mistakes easier to spot.
- I think you may want "elsif" instead of "else if" in places : that addresses a lot of missing "end if" problems

**EDIT : more pointers for updated answer...**

- "Variable Declaration Not Allowed" in the architecture is still an issue ... at first glance I couldn't see why you aren't using signals.
- At second glance :

  ```
   F2 : IF i=3 GENERATE
      BEGIN 
         Grey_box_i: Grey_box PORT MAP(NewP(m), NewBG(m), NewGG(m), DNewG);
         m := m+1;
      END GENERATE F2;
  ```

You can't use variables in a Generate statement like that (because they are outside a process). I suspect you intend their value to be essentially static - a deterministic function of (i) and not holders of state in their own right.

The compiler doesn't know that - it sees more state which could potentially vary at runtime (and you can't grow more hardware at runtime!) so it rejects that idea. For example there is **no ordering** of the hardware generated by `Generate` thus generating the "i=3" case last is perfectly legal and you have **no guarantees** on the value of m. You probably wouldn't like the result!

The solution is simple : eliminate m as a variable and *make* it a function of (i).

```
 function m(x : integer) return integer is
 begin
   case x is
      when 3      => return 0;
      when others => return 1;
   end case;
 end m;

 ... PORT MAP(NewP(m(i)), ...
```

The functions belong in the architecture with the other declarations. Because `i` is fixed (static) within any instance of a generate statement, f(i) - here m(i) - is also static, and though I have not tested this approach I expect it to work.

- As for the unknown identifiers, I see various names such as DNEWG in the above snippet for which I cannot find a declaration; this is trivial to solve.
- you can lose the unnecessary parentheses around if-expressions; they are just clutter left by a passing C programmer

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.
1."better formatting will make it easier to read and mistakes easier to spot." You mean after If etc. if I tab?I was expecting to see if I get a syntax error if I did not tab,that is why I did not fix that.Someone editted it for me.I will correct my project.
2.About the elsif,yes I ll correct that too.I missed them.
3.I will try to understand what you said about the end generate stuff and will come back.
Thanks a lot for the fast help.

Comment: If you can recheck the coding part now that I tried to fix it.Thanks

Comment: 1.Do I need to declare every signal even if it comes out of the PORT MAP of a component as an output? 
2.In the solution you added the returned values will go to the x variable right?So how does this connect with the "i" in the PORT MAP?
Also I don't know if my coding made it clear,but I was trying to use all variables as indicators and sometimes even if "i" reached the value 31,the indicator would have stopped,let's say at 7 cause only inside the if statements his value would rise.
3.I ll fix the parenthesis.

Many many thanks for the help so far.

Comment: 1) the Port Map _maps_ a component port onto an external signal, so yes there needs to be an external signal to map on to. (2) No. The function derives its return value **from** the formal parameter x (to which you pass the actual parameter i). The returned values don't go to any variable; they are used immediately (as an index to array NewP in the example. Yes I understand that the indicator is **a function of** i not a copy of it; that is why I suggest implementing it as ... a function.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation based on structure will often reveal syntax problems, so I took the
liberty to beautify your code.  As you can see in the last part, a lot of the
`if` statements does not have proper closing `end if` statements.  That syntax
error must be fixed, and you may consider using `elsif` for the mutually
exclusive conditions.

Regarding your questions:

1. **What should I put in the sensitivity list:** For a process that describes
   flip-flop(s), the sensitivity should must the clock and any asynchronous reset
   signal(s).  For a process that describes combinatorial logic, the sensitivity
   list must contain all source signals that are used in the combinatorial logic.
   In general, any process you write should be either of these two, so either
   describing flip-flop(s), or describing combinatorial logic.  The process after
   the questions is neither of the two, and have multiple problems: It is not
   allowed to instantiate modules, the Grey_box and Black_box, inside a process,
   and in general you can't use k as a variable, with `:=` assign, without
   declaring it in the process.
2. **How can I make p and g global; is what I have done not enough?**  The p and g
   are available since declared in the architecture, so the problem is due to the
   attempt of instantiating a module i a process, as I noted above.

Overall, you may consider to get a better understanding about the VHDL concept
before starting a larger project like this, since it will then be much easier
to understand and correct any syntax error messages you encounter.

A good place to start is the [Wikipedia VHDL
page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl), where you can look under [Further
reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl#Further_reading).  In order to get a
good VHDL experience I suggest that you dig into some of the resources to learn
the basic concepts.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast answer.I got those questions:

1."For a process that describes combinatorial logic, the sensitivity list must contain all source signals that are used in the combinatorial logic."
Since my logic is i(integer) compared to something how do I do that?Cause I tried to put integer to the parenthesis and it says I can not do that.

2. "the attempt of instantiating a module i a process"

I read that while searching.Can you explain this cause I don't get what it means. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1: The problem is not related to the type (integer), but the element in the sensitivity list must be a signal, thus must be declared in the architecture.

Comment: 1: The problem is not related to the type (integer), but the element in the sensitivity list must be a signal.  2: Brian Drummonds great post describes "two domains", and the modules are put in the wrong domain, since you cant put modules inside a process.   I would suggest that you spend some timing reading about the general principles of VHDL, and write some small examples yourself, since it is not like other programming languages where you can use all statements in all code.  VHDL is a Hardware Description Language (HDL), where text describes hardware, so your code must hardware.

Comment: If you can recheck the coding part now that I tried to fix it.Thanks