# Why won't my VHDL state machine perform subtraction?

Tags: vhdl, state-diagram

This is a simulation of a long division binary divider. The program performs as expected except it will not subtract the divisor from the 5 MSBs of the register no matter how I code it.

Following is the code:

```
            library ieee;
            use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
            use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
            use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

            ENTITY divider IS

                PORT(
                            Clock               :IN STD_LOGIC;
                            Dividend            :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
                            Divisor         :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
                            Reset               :IN STD_LOGIC;
                            St                  :IN STD_LOGIC;

                            outDRegister            :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0):="000000000";
                            outCurrentState         :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0):="000";
                            Quotient            :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
                            Remainder       :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0));
            END divider;

            ARCHITECTURE Behavior of divider IS

            SIGNAL DRegister                        :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL SubOut                           :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
            Signal C,ShiftIn, ShiftRes          :STD_LOGIC;
            Signal ShiftEnable                  :STD_LOGIC;
            Signal tempSt                           :STD_LOGIC:='1';
            TYPE    State_type IS (S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5);
            SIGNAL y:State_type:=S0;

            BEGIN
            PROCESS(Dividend,Divisor,y, st, reset, clock) IS
            BEGIN
            If (Reset='0') THEN
            Y<=S0;
            ELSIF (Clock'EVENT and CLOCK = '1') THEN

                CASE y IS
                    WHEN S0=>
                        IF(st='0' AND tempSt='1' AND reset = '1') THEN
                            DRegister <= '0'&Dividend;
                            y<=S1;
                        ELSIF(st='1' AND reset = '1') THEN
                            Quotient    <= DRegister(3 DOWNTO 0);
                            Remainder   <= DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4);
                            y<=S0;
                        END IF;
                        outDRegister<=DRegister;
                        outCurrentState<="000";
                        tempSt<=st; 

                    WHEN S1=>
                        IF(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)>=Divisor) THEN
                            y<=S0;
                        ELSE
                            DRegister <= (DRegister(7 DOWNTO 0) & '0');
                            y<=S2;
                        END IF;
                        outDRegister<=DRegister;
                        outCurrentState<="001";
                    WHEN S2=>
                        IF(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)>=Divisor) THEN
                            DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)<=(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4) - Divisor);--Does not work!! Does nothing.
                            DRegister <= DRegister(7 DOWNTO 0) & '1';
                        ELSE
                            DRegister <= DRegister(7 DOWNTO 0) & '0';
                        END IF;
                        outDRegister<=DRegister;
                        outCurrentState<="010";     
                        y<=S3;

                    WHEN S3=>
                        IF(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)>=Divisor) THEN
                            DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)<=(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4) - Divisor);--Does not work!! Does nothing.
                            DRegister <= DRegister(7 DOWNTO 0) & '1';
                        ELSE
                            DRegister <= DRegister(7 DOWNTO 0) & '0';

                        END IF;
                        outDRegister<=DRegister;
                        outCurrentState<="011";
                        y<=S4;

                    WHEN S4=>
                        IF(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)>=Divisor) THEN
                            DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)<=(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4) - Divisor);--Does not work!! Does nothing.
                            DRegister <= DRegister(7 DOWNTO 0) & '1';
                        ELSE
                            DRegister <= DRegister(7 DOWNTO 0) & '0';
                        END IF;
                        outDRegister<=DRegister;
                        outCurrentState<="100";
                        y<=S5;

                    WHEN S5=>   
                        IF(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)>=Divisor) THEN
                            DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4)<=(DRegister(8 DOWNTO 4) - Divisor);--Does not work!! Does nothing.
                        END IF;
                        outDRegister<=DRegister;
                        outCurrentState<="101";

                        y<=S0;

                END CASE;

            END IF;




            END PROCESS;


            END Behavior;
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is to read up on the difference between variable and signal assignment in VHDL. Your problem lies there. One solution involves an intermediate variable for the problem states; another involves rewriting a signal assignment.

My usual explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532), there's a link at the bottom of the page to "VHDL's Crown Jewel" which is also very well worth reading.

Also note:

- There are better libraries for arithmetic : ieee.numeric_std rather than std_logic_unsigned or std_logic_arith or (worst of all) mixing the two.
- There are better data type for arithmetic than std_logic_vector : ieee.numeric_std.unsigned (or signed), or even subtypes of `integer` or `natural`;
- As you are writing a nice clean single-process state machine, its sensitivity list ONLY needs `clock, reset`
- You can lose the parentheses around conditional expressions, `If Reset='0' Then` is fine (this is not your father's C compiler)
- `rising_edge(Clock)` is preferred to `Clock'EVENT and CLOCK = '1'`
  but these are all peripheral to the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic code part, as you also marked, is:

```
...
DRegister(8 downto 4) <= (DRegister(8 downto 4) - Divisor);  --Does not work!! Does nothing.
DRegister             <= DRegister(7 downto 0) & '1';
...
```

In VHDL, the value of a signal is not updated until the end of the current
simulation cycle, so the value of `DRegister` used in the second assign to
`DRegister` above is not altered by the first assign to `DRegister`.

So, the effect of the first assign to `DRegister(8 downto 4)` is overridden by
the second assign to all bits in `DRegister`, whereby the subtraction of the
`Divisor` does not have any effect.

One way to correct the code, so to make only a single assign to all `DRegister` bits.

You may want to take a look at David Koontz answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20104800/2352082 since this covers a similar issue.