# Unable to split a Vector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am unable to update reg_1 and reg_2 vectors by splitting reg_mem?
   This is my code in VHDL which i had written in MODELSIM:
   In other program i tried to split another vector into two parts and store them into two different Vectors.It worked fine.But same syntax is not working in this code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Register_unit is
port (
  reg_read : in std_logic;
  reg_write : in std_logic;
  reg_mem : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  reg_start : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  reg_end : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  reg_write_comp : out std_logic;
  reg_read_comp : out std_logic;
  reg_1 : inout std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  reg_2 : inout std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end Register_unit;

architecture Register_unit_arch of Register_unit is
begin

  process (reg_read,reg_write)
  begin
    if (reg_read = '1' and reg_write = '0') then
      reg_end <= reg_mem;
      reg_read_comp <= '1'; 
    elsif (reg_write = '1' and reg_read = '0') then
      reg_mem <= reg_start;
      reg_write_comp <= '1';
    end if;
    reg_1 <= reg_mem(1 downto 0); --reg_1 is not getting updated 
    reg_2 <= reg_mem(3 downto 2); --reg2 is not getting updated
  end process;

end Register_unit_arch;
```

Comment: Sensitivity list error on asynch process. One fix : move the split outside the process. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532 Also note there's no way to reset the `reg_*_comp` signals.

Answer (score 0):

`reg_1` and `reg_2` is updated but they are updated to *previous* value of the `reg_mem`. This line;

```
reg_mem <= reg_start;
```

is not in effect until the end of process. You are making the `reg_1` and `reg_2` assignment before `reg_mem` has it's new value!

VHDL doesn't work top down like a programming language even if you are in a `process`.

In your case you should either use a variable (*) or directly assign from `reg_start` like this;

```
reg_1 <= reg_start(1 downto 0);
reg_2 <= reg_start(3 downto 2);
```

(*) variables are immediately assigned in a process, you can use them similar to programming language variables

Comment: @HeyYOThanks very much I understood where did i go wrong Just changed the process variables and everything is correctly working