# Write followed by Read in VHDL process

Tags: vhdl

The following code is for a very simple program in VHDL.

```
entity ent is
    port(
        clk: in std_logic;
        out_value: out std_logic;
    );
end entity ent;

architecture ent_arch of ent is
    signal counter: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            counter <= counter + 1;
            if counter = 10 then
                counter <= (others => '0') ;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end ent_arch;
```

Imagine *counter* = 9 and we enter in the *if* statement (if rising_edge(clk)). The first statement *counter <= counter + 1* will assign 10 to *counter*. My question is "Is the *if* statetement (if counter = 10) evaluted as *true* in this entrance or in the next entrance of the process?". In other words "For this comparison in this entrance of the process, is *counter = 10* due to the previous statement?"

Thanks a lot for any answer!

Comment: Answered many places ... including here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Comment: Variables values are immediately available while signals are scheduled for update in a projected output waveform queue. There's an implicit 'after 0 fs' after a signal assignment and any secondary unit is legal for 0 with any resolution limit. The value of counter will be available in the next simulation cycle the process is active.  Instead, `iif counter = 9 then counter <= (others => '0'); else counter <= counter +1; end if;`  When it's 9 set to zero, else increment.

Answer (score 0):

Signal assignments are always delayed. You didn't specified a delay explicitly using the `after` keyword, thus the assignment is delayed for one delta cycle (same as `after 0 fs`). That means, that the value of the expression on the right side of this statement:

```
counter <= counter + 1;
```

will be assigned to `counter` at the beginning of the **next** simulation cycle.

But, all remaining statements in your process, are executed in the **current** simulation cycle. Thus, this read of the counter value,

```
if counter = 10 then
```

will still use the old value, so that, the counter will be reseted when it is already 10 at the rising clock edge. The counter counts from 0 to 10 inclusive.

The delay of at least one delta cycle, easily allows to swap the content of registers:

```
-- within declarative part of architecture
signal reg_a, reg_b : std_logic;

-- within architecture body
process(clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    reg_a <= reg_b;
    reg_b <= reg_a;  -- assign old value of reg_a ! 
  end if;
end process;
```