# how do sequential assignments to a signal inside a process behave

Tags: vhdl

I'm wondering, how sequential assignments to the same signal inside of a process are treated in VHDL.

I've seen code like the following:

```vhdl
ENTITY some_entity IS
    ...
    ...
END some_entity;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF some_entity IS
    SIGNAL some_signal : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN PROCESS (clk)
    ...
    ...
    IF condition1 THEN
        some_signal <= "01";
    ELSE
        some_signal <= (others => '0');
    END IF;

    IF condition2 THEN
        some_signal <= "10";
    ELSE
        some_signal <= (others => '0');
    END IF;

    IF condition3 THEN
        some_signal <= "11";
    ELSE
        some_signal <= (others => '0');
    END IF;
    ...
    ...
END PROCESS;
...
...
END Behavioral;
```

At first I thought, that this doesn't really make sense, because `some_signal` is assigned multiple values at the same time. Vivado is synthesizing it without complaints though and after a little research about processes, I thought it might actually behave equivalent to the following:

```
ENTITY some_entity IS
    ...
    ...
END some_entity;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF some_entity IS
    SIGNAL some_signal : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN PROCESS (clk)
    ...
    ...
    IF condition3 THEN
        some_signal <= "11";
    ELSIF condition 2 THEN
        some_signal <= "10";
    ELSIF condition1 THEN
        some_signal <= "01";
    ELSE
        some_signal <= (others => '0');
    END IF;
    ...
    ...
END PROCESS;
...
...
END Behavioral;
```

Is this notion correct? And if not, what does the first code example actually do?

Comment: "last assignment wins" ... reversing the conditions as you did is correct ... however as the last `if` statement has an assignment in both arms, it overrides both earlier statements : you will never see their execution.  Output will only be `"11"` or `"00"`. Key terms to understand : delta cycles, postponed assignment.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know. I haven't thought about the last if overriding the earlier ifs, but thinking about it, it's quite obvious. Why didn't you post this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Last assignment wins" ... reversing the conditions as you did is correct ... however as the last if statement has an assignment in both arms, it overrides both earlier statements : you will never see their execution (unless it isn't executed as a result of some other condition)

Output will only be `"11"` or `"00"`.

Key terms to understand : delta cycles, postponed assignment.

You might find my [standard answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532) to similar questions useful background. It's really key to understanding what signals are for - they are how VHDL solves the problems of inter-process communication.

Comment: I actually read that "standard answer" before asking this question, but it didn't make it clear that assignments to a signal can be overwritten during one run of a process. Thanks again for this answer.

Comment: There's a time ordered queue of scheduled values for every signal assigned in a process referred to as a *Projected Output Waveform*.  It retains only one entry for any particular simulation time.  An assignment scheduling a value supplants the projected value at a particular time or earlier times if present. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement for an in depth description.