# ISIM signal assignment delay

Tags: vhdl

I expected signal 'delay' to be one clock cycle late wrt to the entities' port 'input', but ISIM shows no phase shift. 
I thought there is always is a delay between signal assignment and actual value (when the process suspends), but I don't seee it here.

Why is this?

[image]

Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity test is
Port ( clk:   in  std_logic;
          input: in  std_logic
        );
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is
    signal delay: std_logic:= '0';

    begin   
    proc1: process(clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            delay <= input;                -- ISIM shows no delay between them
        end if;             
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Testbench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;


ENTITY tb_testbench_test IS
END tb_testbench_test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_testbench_test IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT) 
COMPONENT test
PORT(
          clk:   in  std_logic;
          input: in  std_logic
    );
END COMPONENT;


--Inputs
signal clk: std_logic := '0';
signal input: std_logic := '0';

-- Clock period definitions
constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
uut: test PORT MAP (
      clk => clk,
      input => input
    );

-- Clock process definitions
clk_process :process
begin
    clk <= '0';
    wait for clk_period/2;
    clk <= '1';
    wait for clk_period/2;
end process;


-- Stimulus process
stim_proc: process
begin       
  wait for clk_period * 9.5;    

    input <= '1';
    wait for clk_period;
    input <= '0';

  wait;
end process;

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test bench describes `clk` and `input` going high at the same time. You then have a process in your entity that is looking for a `rising_edge` of `clk`. Therefore, when your process runs, and asks 'was there a rising edge of the clock?', if the answer to this is 'yes', i.e. the clock signal had just become `'1'`, then the state of the `input` must also be `'1'`, because the two signals changed at the same time. The `delay` signal then takes this new `input`, giving the result you see.

A more realistic scenario would be a change of the `input` being *caused* by a rising edge of `clk`. You can easily simulate this by modifying your stimulus process:

```
stim_proc: process
begin       
  wait for clk_period * 9.5;    
  wait until clk = '1';  -- Sit here until we have seen a rising edge of `clk`
  input <= '1'; -- This assignment now happens *after* the clock edge
  wait until clk = '1';
  input <= '0';

  wait;
end process;
```

Comment: "... a change of the input being caused by a rising edge of clk" was exactly what I had in mind, although incorrectly implemented. Your testbench modification did the trick. I still see 'clk' and 'input' rising at the same time (and 'delay' now one clock cycle later), but I guess the first "wait until clk = '1';" implements a delta-cycle delay, making a difference, right?

Comment: It'll implement a delay as long as necessary. Which in this specific case will be a single delta cycle.

Comment: @user2286339 I didn't go into delta cycles because I didn't think it was needed to understand what went wrong. You are correct that the effect of my change is that the assignment to `input` happens one delta cycle after the clock transition. In a more sophisticated simulator, you can view these delta steps using an 'expanded time mode' or similar, but ISim doesn't seem to have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The delay between a signal assignment and the appearance of its value is ... one delta cycle. And the time taken by one delta cycle is 0 fS.

What your testbench represents is a race condition whereby you present the input signal and the clock signal at exactly the same time - i.e. in the same delta cycle.

In real hardware, what would happen would be a coin-toss whether the input was seen by this clock edge or the next, or would be some intermediate value when the clock edge happened, raising the possibility of [metastable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metastability_in_electronics) operation.
The simulation has accidentally alerted you to the possibility of such mis-operation.

If you delay the data signal by even one delta cycle (as is guaranteed to happen if it was the output from a previous clocked process) such as a concurrent signal assignment outside the process, you will eliminate the timing hazard and see the delay you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. N.B. is there some exhaustive text on delta-cylcles, theory and application-wise? I had some exposure to it, but it's been some time.

Comment: Nothing that jumps out as "must read" specifically on that.  I sometimes refer in answers to my own Q&A here which covers the basics, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Comment: Delta cycles come from CONLAN's BCL (Base CONLAN) model of computation, where they are called steps. See *On the Origin of VHDL's Delta Delays*, SUMIT GHOSH, Int. J. Engng Ed. Vol. 20, No. 4, pp. 638-645, 2004, *CONLAN Report*, R. Piloty, M. Barbacci, D. Borrione, D. Dietmeyer, F. Hill,  P. Skelly, Springer-Verlag 1983. There are examples of the time model going back to 1971. For application, *VHDL for Engineers*, Kenneth L. Short ISBN-13: 978-0-13-142478-4.

Comment: There's also [Title Studies on Logic Simulation and Hardware Description Languages( Dissertation_全文 )](http://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/74578/1/D_Ishiura_Nagisa.pdf), Nagisa Isiura, a Phd thesis, Kyoto University 1991, around section 7.2.2 Modeling of a Zero Delay. There are also `postponed`  processes introduce in VHDL in IEEE Std 1076-1993.