# I am getting wrong signal for one CLK period in my waveform

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I have this scheme

[image: scheme]

I have to write structural VHDL design for it.

So these are my components:
MUX:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity mux is
port(
    A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
    B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
    Sel : in bit;
    Z : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
    );
 end mux;

 architecture Beh of mux is 
 begin

Z <= A when Sel='1'else 
B;
end Beh;
```

REG:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity reg is
   port( 
    C : STD_LOGIC;
    LD : in bit; 
    Reg_in : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
    R_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
    );
end reg;


architecture Beh of reg is  
begin

process (C) 
begin
    if (rising_edge (C)) then
        if (LD = '1') then
            R_out <= Reg_in;  
        end if;
    end if;
end process;


end Beh;
```

TOP:

```
 library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity top is
   port( 
   LDA, LDB, S1, S0 : in bit; 
   CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
    X, Y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
    RB : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
    );
end top;

architecture Beh of top is  

signal regB_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
signal regA_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal mux1_res :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);  
signal mux2_res :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
begin      

Mux1: entity mux(Beh) 
port map 
(
    A => X,
    B => regB_out,
    Sel => S1,
    Z => mux1_res
);

RegA: entity reg(Beh)
port map 
(
    LD => LDA,
    C => CLK,
    Reg_in => mux1_res,
    R_out => regA_out
);

Mux2: entity mux(Beh) 
port map 
(
    A => regA_out,
    B => Y,
    Sel => S0,
    Z => mux2_res
);
 RB<=regB_out;
RegB: entity reg(Beh)
port map 
(
    LD => LDB,
    C => CLK,
    Reg_in => mux2_res,
    R_out => regB_out
);   



end Beh;
```

I am not sure I wrote bind between RB, regB_out and B correctly. And in the waveform when S1 and S0 both equal 0, I get nonsence for 1 CLK period. Like on the screenshot at 600ns '01' on RB shouldn't be there. Can some one help me to find mistakes?

TestBench:

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
 use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;
 use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

 ENTITY tbt is
 END tbt;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tbt IS


     COMPONENT TOP  

       PORT (
       CLK : in STD_LOGIC;   
       LDA, LDB, S1, S0 : in bit;
       X, Y : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0); 
       RB : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
       );
    END COMPONENT;


   signal CLK_sig   : std_logic;  
   signal LDA_sig, LDB_sig, S1_sig, S0_sig : bit :='0'; 
   signal X_sig, Y_sig, RB_sig      : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="00000000";   


   constant CLK_period : time := 100 ns;  
   constant s_per : time := 50 ns;
begin

-------------------------------------------------------------

uut: TOP PORT MAP (
    CLK =>  CLK_sig,
    LDA =>  LDA_sig,       
    LDB =>  LDB_sig,
    S1  =>  S1_sig,
    S0  =>  S0_sig,  
    X   =>  X_sig,    
    Y  => Y_sig,
    RB=>  RB_sig 
    );

-------------------------------------------------------------

CLK_process :process
begin
    CLK_sig <= '0';
    wait for CLK_period/2;
    CLK_sig <= '1';
    wait for CLK_period/2;
end process;

-------------------------------------------------------------

stim_proc: process    
     variable itertion_backwards : integer := 255;
    variable itertion_forward : integer := 0;

begin

    wait for CLK_period;

        for itertion_forward in 0 to 254 loop


                X_sig <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_SIGNED(INTEGER(itertion_forward),8));  


                Y_sig <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_SIGNED(INTEGER(itertion_backwards),8));     


                wait for CLK_period;
                S1_sig<= not S1_sig;

                wait for CLK_period;  
                S0_sig<= not S0_sig;  

                wait for CLK_period;
                LDA_sig<= not LDA_sig;

                wait for CLK_period;
                LDB_sig<= not LDB_sig;   


            itertion_backwards := itertion_backwards - 1;

        end loop;

    wait;

end process;


end;
```

[image: waveform]

Comment: Why did you use `bit` type? Try `std_logic` instead.

Comment: You'd expect the length of `LDA`, `LDB`, `S0`, and `S1` to be multiples of the clock period in a synchronous system. Noting the suffix on `CLK_sig`, etc. it appears your mistakes lie in a not provided testbench. The transition at 600 ns is caused by `LDA` being valid while S0 changes (it's goes to '0' during the same delta cycle `CLK` goes to '1'). This would be apparent if `regA_out` were shown. Offset your stimuli from the register active clock edge. Entities `mux` and `reg` aren't visible in `top` without `use work.all;` or selected names (e.g. `entity work.reg`), what simulator?

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I added my testbench to my post. I sort of fixed this last night, in testbench after assigning value to Y_sig there's wait for CLK_period, I moved it after LDB_sig assignment and got rid of that '01'.
But my main point is about this '01' is that at the same time when LDA is 1, LDB is 1 too, so it should take Y_signal straight to REG_B and on RB output. Like this '01' is stored at REG_A but it shouldn't be on output RB at all. Or it's happening because there's no delays and it kind of catches this '01' because S0 falling synchronized with CLK rising?

Comment: You should read up on [delta cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652630/delta-cycles-and-waveforms). And if you don't want to deal with it, make sure all of your signals change on a clock edge with `wait until rising_edge(CLK);` also in your testbench

Comment: Didn't know such thing even exists. Thanks :)