# Signal assignment in a clocked process happening instantly

Tags: vhdl

So I have a simple enough clocked process that assigns the value of one `std_logic_vector` to another.

```
capture_proc: process(clk) 
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        captured_data <= sdram_din; 
    end if;
end process;
```

My problem is that on the rising edge of `clk` the value that is put into  `captured_data` is readable by other processes on the same rising edge.

My understanding of signal assignment in sequential code is that in a simulation it actually happens right before the next trigger a clock cycle later. This is not what happens in my case as seen below.

In the following simulation I forced the value of `sdram_din` to 0x0000 on a falling edge and on the next rising edge the value assignment takes place. Why does the value appear instantly but not a cycle later?

[Waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuaHW.png)

All of the code can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/SDMnB0EE).

Comment: See [Delta Cycles and Waveforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652630/delta-cycles-and-waveforms).

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that on the rising edge of clk the value that is put into captured_data is readable by other processes **on the same rising edge**.

(Emphasis is mine)
The waveform shown does not have the behavior. To show that you would need to add another signal, derived from `captured_data` using the same clock.

> My understanding of signal assignment in sequential code is that in a simulation it actually happens right before the next trigger a clock cycle later.

I don't understand where this expectation comes from. The moment the clock rises the signal `sdram_din` is sampled. The same holds for all other signals which have the 'rising_edge(clk)` condition. The only think special is that all values are first sampled and only *after all samples are taken* are the values assigned.

> Why does the value appear instantly

As I wrote above: after the signals are sampled they are assigned. Immediately. In a simulation no noticeable delay is present. (For details look up 'VHDL delta time'.) 
Any signal which is combinatorial derived from `captured_data` will appear also with no delay as in an ideal simulation there is no delay.