# How are sequential statements inside a vhdl process synthesized?

Tags: vhdl, sequential

I have some difficulties understanding how sequential statements inside a vhdl process are synthesized.

The IEEE standard reference manual Std 1076-2008 states:

> Sequential statements are used to define algorithms for the execution of a subprogram or process; they execute in the order in which they appear.

It's easy to understand how it works in simulation since simulation is done by a CPU, that is build for sequential execution. In this case the hardest thing is to simulate **concurrent** executions, and this is done with the trick of [delta delays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652630/delta-cycles-and-waveforms/43669162).
But what about the synthesis? I don't understand how it is possible for two statements to be sequential in a fully logical architecture...

Any help ?

An example process:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity example is
    Port (clk, rst, A : in STD_LOGIC; B : out STD_LOGIC);
end example;

architecture example_arch of example is
begin
    process(clk, rst)
        variable C : STD_LOGIC;
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            C := '0';
            B <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if A = '1' then
                E := '1';
            else
                E := '0';
            end if;

            -- then sequentially ?
            if E = '1' then
                B <= '1';
            else
                B <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end example_arch;
```

Comment: My answer to a somewhat related question may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Answer (score 1):

The synthesis tool will analyze the process and turn it into gates and flip-flops in a way that is faithful to the *sequential* (but also "instantaneous") execution of the process.

For example, your `process` (where I assume you meant to assign-to, and check the value of, variable `C`, not `E`) should be turned (synthesized) into a simple `DFF` with an asynchronous reset.