# Why don't signals update inside process?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to insert 4 groups of 16 bits to form 2 numbers of 32 bits (in IEEE 754 format). 
This is my code:

```
  entity insert is
    Port (
           Clk : in STD_LOGIC; 
           Enter : in STD_LOGIC;
           Number: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);

           Sign_A : out STD_LOGIC;
           Exponent_A : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Mantissa_A : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0);

           Sign_B : out STD_LOGIC;
           Exponent_B : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Mantissa_B : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0)
           );
end insert;

architecture Behavioral of insert is

begin
proc: process(Enter,Number,Clk)
--variable cnt :integer :=0;
variable cnt: integer := 0;
variable number_A:std_logic_Vector(31 downto 0):=(others =>'0');
variable number_B:std_logic_Vector(31 downto 0):=(others =>'0');
variable intermNumber:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin

if(rising_edge(Clk))then
    if (Enter ='1' ) then
        case cnt is
        when 0=> number_A(31 downto 16) := Number;
        when 1=> number_A(15 downto 0) := Number;
        when 2=> number_B(31 downto 16) := Number;
        when 3=> number_B(15 downto 0) := Number;
        when others =>  number_B(15 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
        end case;
        cnt := cnt +1;  
    end if;

    Sign_A<=number_A(31);
    Exponent_A<=number_A(30 downto 23);
    Mantissa_A<="1" & number_A(22 downto 0);

    Sign_B<=number_B(31);
    Exponent_B<=number_B(30 downto 23);
    Mantissa_B<="1" & number_B(22 downto 0);

end if;
end process;
```

When I ran simulation, I observed that my signals (cnt2 and the others signals) don't change. I tried to declare a variable cnt inside process, but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong? Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you :)

Testbench:

```
entity test is

    --  Port ( );

    end test;

    architecture Behavioral of test is
    component insert
        Port ( Clk : in STD_LOGIC;
               Enter : in STD_LOGIC;
               Number : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);

               Sign_A : out STD_LOGIC;
               Exponent_A : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
               Mantissa_A : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0);

               Sign_B : out STD_LOGIC;
               Exponent_B : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
               Mantissa_B : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0)
               );
    end component;

    signal Enter :  STD_LOGIC;
    signal  Number :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);          
    signal  Sign_A :  STD_LOGIC;
    signal  Exponent_A :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
    signal  Mantissa_A :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0);          
    signal  Sign_B :  STD_LOGIC;
    signal  Exponent_B :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
    signal   Mantissa_B :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0);
    signal Clk : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    constant CLK_PERIOD : Time := 10 ns;

    begin

    DUT: insert port map
      (
      Clk=>Clk,
      Enter=>Enter,
      Number=>Number,
      Sign_A=>Sign_A,
      Mantissa_A=>Mantissa_A,
      Exponent_A=>Exponent_A,
      Sign_B=>Sign_B,
      Mantissa_B=>Mantissa_B,
      Exponent_B=>Exponent_B);


    gen_clk:process
    begin
        Clk <= '1';
        wait for (CLK_PERIOD/2);
        Clk <= '0';
        wait for (CLK_PERIOD/2);
    end process gen_clk;


    genereare: process
    begin
    Number<="0011111101011001";
    Enter<='1';
    Enter<='0';
    wait for CLK_PERIOD;

    Number<="1001100110011010";
    Enter<='1';
    Enter<='0';
    wait for CLK_PERIOD;

    Number<="0100000100100100";
    Enter<='1';
    Enter<='0';
    wait for CLK_PERIOD;

    Number<="1100110011001101";
    Enter<='1';
    Enter<='0';
    wait for CLK_PERIOD;


    end process;

    end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The code you posted will not compile with the typos (numar vs number).   That said, if you are creating combinational logic, you need all signal inputs to the process on the sensitivity list.   In your case this is:  Enter, Cnt2, and Number.    If your synthesis tool allows, I would recommend using the keyword "all" on any combinational logic process - note this is a VHDL-2008 addition, so you will need the appropriate settings and even then it may not be supported  - also note if "all" is not supported file a bug report against the tool.

Comment: The problem with number vs numar appeared when i edited the code for this post. In project it's ok.  "all" keyword it's not supported. I added cnt2 to process sensitivity list, but this didn't resolve my problem...

Comment: please show our test bench.

Comment: The code will not synthesize something useful. `cnt2 <= cnt2 + 1;` may ripple from 0 to 1, to 2, to 3 when enter is '1'. Using the output of the cnt2 counter as part of the control path combinatorially is also not hazard free. Your code doesn't describe RTL synthesis eligible (clocked) registers for cnt2, Number_A or Number_B. There's nothing that allows repeated execution (cnt2 sticks at 3). Why signal values 'don't change' can't be determined without a [mcve] providing stimuli and expected results (e.g. a testbench). Don't change when and for what inputs?

Comment: I updated the code and I added the testbench I am using.

Comment: `Enter<='1'; Enter<='0';` <-- there's your problem. As stated many times ([again yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163596/6717178)): in VHDL signals do not change instantly. They change on the next delta cycle. Without a `wait` statement between the assignments, `Enter` will therefore stay `'0'`: the second assignment will overwrite the first.

Comment: p.s., because all statements in the process loop are confined within a `rising_edge(Clk)` condition, you only need `Clk` in the process sensitivity list.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem