# Why does signal assignment not execute on the first iteration? VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL. I heard that signal assignment only updates at the end of a process and will only use the most recent assignment, so I wanted to test it out. How come the value for temp did not update at the end of the first process(i=0) even though I already have an initial value for a,b,c? It only started updating the value for temp on the second iteration(i=1).

Code I used to test:

```
architecture Behavioral of test is
    signal a    : integer := 1;
    signal b    : integer := 2;
    signal c    : integer := 3;
    signal i    : integer := 0;
    signal temp, temp2  : integer;
begin
    process is
    begin
        report "-----Start Here-----(" & integer'image(i) & ")";
        temp <= a;      report "1:" & integer'image(temp);
        temp <= b;      report "2:" & integer'image(temp);
        temp <= c;      report "3:" & integer'image(temp);

        temp2 <= a;     report "4:" & integer'image(temp2);
        temp2 <= temp;  report "5:" & integer'image(temp2);
        report "-----End Here----------------------------";
        
        i <= i + 1;
        wait for 10ns;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

OUTPUT:

```
-----Start Here-----(0)
1: -2147483648                  
2: -2147483648
3: -2147483648
4: -2147483648
5: -2147483648
-----End Here----------------------------
-----Start Here-----(1)
1: 3
2: 3
3: 3
4: -2147483648
5: -2147483648
-----End Here----------------------------
-----Start Here-----(2)
1: 3
2: 3
3: 3
4: 3
5: 3
-----End Here----------------------------
```

Comment: See the [answer to sequential execution in process statement in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163596/16145658) where  the question's distinction from yours lies the use of a process sensitive to a clock event and the process only takes one clock to traverse. VHDL LRM extracts are used to describe what happens during simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a signal assignment occurs, it schedules the value to be updated when a process hits a wait statement (when there is no sensitivity list) or when the process completes (when there is a sensitivity list).
In your process, at time 0, The process starts. `temp` has the initial value `integer'low`. You assign `a`, then `b`, then finally `c` (which wins, and `temp` will be scheduled to have `c` assigned). Remember, there is no wait statement hit by this point, so the signal assignments will not have occured yet. Hence why the `report` all report the initial value for `temp`.

If you move the report statments to be after the wait statement, you would see the updated values.