# Function Wash not increasing value in sec signal in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus, digital-design

I'm very new to VHDL and for my digital design project I have to make a simulation of a washing machine in a DE10-Lite FPGA with finite states.

Everything seems good so far but when it's turn for the impure function `Wash` to work, it looks like signal `sec` is not summing up one, and therefore never leaves the state.

Any idea on how to correct this?

This is the full code. Impure `Wash` function is declared in the second process and signal `sec` is part of the architecture variables.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
  
entity WM is --Wash

    port (  
        p,m,s,w,r,d,c,t: in std_logic; --power,mode,start,wash,rinse,dry,clock,tank
        pl,ml,wl,rl,dl,motor: out std_logic --powerLed,modeLed,washLed,rinseLed,dryLed,motor
            );
                
end WM;

architecture bhv of WM is

    signal sec: integer:= 0;
    signal e: boolean := false;
    
    type t_state is (off,autoL,autoP,manualL);
    signal state : t_state;
    
    begin
    
        process(p,m,w,r,d,s)
        
        begin
        
        if p = '0' then
        
            state <= off; --off
                        
        else
                        
            if m = '1' then
            
                state <= autoL; --auto
                
                if s = '1' then
                    state <= autoP; 
                else
                    state <= autoL;
                end if;
                        
            else
                
                state <= manualL; --manual
                
            end if;
        
        end if;
            
        end process;    
        
        process(state,c,t,e,sec)
        
        impure function WashFill(Seconds : integer:= 0) return boolean is
        begin
        
        if t = '1' then
            return true;
            
        else
            if c = '1' then
                wl <= '0';
            else
                wl <= '1';
            end if;
            
            return false;
        end if; 
        
        end function;
        
        impure function Wash(Seconds : integer:= 0) return boolean is
        begin
        
            if c = '1' then
              sec <= sec + 1;
         else
              sec <= sec;
         end if;

         if sec = 5 then
              sec <= 0;
              motor <= '0';
              return true;
         else
              motor <= '1';
              wl <= '1';
              return false;
         end if;  
        
        end function;   
        
        
        impure function WashDrain(Seconds : integer:= 0) return boolean is
        begin
        
        if t = '0' then
            return true;
            
        else
            if c = '1' then
                wl <= '0';
            else
                wl <= '1';
            end if;
            
            return false;
        end if; 
        
        end function;   
        
        begin
        
            case state is
                
                when off =>
                
                    pl <= '0';
                    ml <= '0';
                    wl <= '0';
                    rl <= '0';
                    dl <= '0';
                    motor <= '0';
                            
                when autoL =>
                
                    pl <= '1';
                    ml <= '1';
                    wl <= '1';
                    rl <= '1';
                    dl <= '1';
                    motor <= '0';
                    
                when autoP =>
                
                    if WashFill(Seconds => 5) then
                        if Wash(Seconds => 5) then
                            if WashDrain(Seconds => 5) then
                                end if;
                        end if;
                    end if; 
                    
                when manualL =>
                
                    pl <= '1';
                    ml <= '0';
                    wl <= '0';
                    rl <= '0';
                    dl <= '0';
                    motor <= '0';
                
                --when others =>
                    --motor <='1';
                    
            end case;
        
        end process;
    
    end bhv;
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Do you have a testbench? Can you see what is going on in simulation? counters etc generally do not work without a clock. Your functions all take a `Seconds` parameter that is not used within the functions. I recommend not using `impure functions`  (or even pure functions) until you understand the basics of digital logic and VHDL fundamentals. I recommend removing the functions and doing the code directly in the process.

Comment: Make sure you understand the different semantics of variable and signal assignments. This code reads as if you might not have grasped postponed assignment and delta cycles. This may help a little : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532  And as Tricky says, write a testbench and take a deep look inside, in simulation.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement and 10.2 Wait statement on how to construct a process sensitivity list. Note an assignment sensitive to a signal level with feedback and an increment or decrement will produce a gated oscillator because of inversion. Counters and state registers should be assigned on clock edges to match post synthesis behavior. Provide a [mcve] here implying a testbench and a specific issue instead of the observation the sec counter isn't counting.